# Create a custom Windows 7 install ISO

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image, windows-installation

I regularly format my system and perform a fresh install of Windows 7. Yet the most annoying thing is having to install every update and reinstall all my programs.

I've been trying to find out how I could create an ISO of my fresh system, so that I can load that instead of having to go through all the hassle to install every update/program. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any methods. Has anyone else tried to do this?

Comment: You can try creating backup and restore. Burn backup to a DVD..

Comment: @Pradip, that will not help him to restore programs. And the question is clearly about programs!

Comment: WEll, there's [ninite](http://ninite.com/) if you're looking for a simple way to manage and update apps. Limited list, but it covers a lot of useful apps. If you want a full-blown package manager (like `homebrew` or `apt-get`), you can give [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) a try. It's still in a state of progress, but it works and has many more packages than Ninite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called taking an image of your system at a specific point (for example, fresh install, main programs and drivers on).

> Click on Start go to Getting Started and then select Back up your
>   files.
>
> Next click on the Create a system image hyperlink.
>
> Decide where you want to save the image. You can choose an external
>   drive, burn to multiple DVD’s, or store it on a network location.
>
> You can include other drives if you want as well but remember that
>   will add to the size of the final image.
>
> At the confirmation screen notice the amount of space the image may
>   take. If something doesn’t look right you can still go back from this
>   point and make adjustments.
>
> A progress meter is displayed while the images is created and backed
>   up. In this example a disk of about 15GB in size took under 20 minutes
>   backed up to an external drive. Times will vary depending on your
>   system and where you’re backing it up to.
>
> After the process is complete you get the option to create a system
>   repair disc which you should do and make sure to save it in a secure
>   location.
>
> When it comes time to restore the image, you will be able to use the
>   System Recovery Options to get the system back.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/)

Comment: Oh wow ... I feel like an idiot now.